# Pso based image enhacment

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, optimization, computer-vision

I want to enhance my image  by using pso based gray level image enhacment.I send the algorithm but i dont understand how I get particle of my image.[pso paper](http://www.isical.ac.in/~ash/gray_level_apurba.pdf)

Comment: That image doesn't say anything at all. You might get better luck if you can link a paper or a text where the algorithm is described.

Comment: @imaluengo http://www.isical.ac.in/~ash/gray_level_apurba.pdf

Comment: @imaluengo have you got any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to carefully read the section `B. Proposed methodology`. It says something like this:

> Now our aim is to find the best set of values
>   for these four parameters which can produce the optimal result
>   and to perform this work *PSO* is used. ***P* number of particles
>   are initialized, each with four parameters *a*, *b*, *c*, and *k* by the
>   random values within their range and corresponding random
>   velocities.**

So there you have your *particle generation*. Each *particle* is a set of 4 random values.

Comment: Each particle is same image but all parameters are different.Is it true ?I have one image and main purpose is generate optimal values of all parameters.is it true thanks in advance @imaluengo

Comment: @raddokmaddok Yep, you basically generate ***P*** images with 4 different parameters (initially random within a range). Each of the images is evaluated and moved towards an improved version with the update steps. The best image remains.

Comment: Paper say that i must update position and velocity i calculate fitness value of image (random 4 variables). What if i calculate velocity and position.where can i use them.when i calculate fitness value i dont need position and velocity. @imaluengo thanks in advance.